# Changing Date to Text format upon export from Access to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, export-to-excel

I need to be able to run an export, and my three date fields need to come out in text format MM/DD/YYYY. They will all be populated with same date. How can I do this?

Three date columns below, followed by VBA text in Access for exporting. Please help!
The end user needs to be able to take this and import it into another tool without making changes, date formats are not accepted.

```
'Public Const ActivityStartDateCol As String = "E"
'Public Const ActivityEndDateCol As String = "F"
'Public Const PaymentDateCol As String = "K"

Option Compare Database
Public Const UploadTemplateFilePath As String = "\\mmpfs04.endo.san\Shared\ASSC\Cegedim\Upload Template\PCard_DB_Upload_Template_Final.xlsx"
Public Const ActivityCountryCol As String = "A"
Public Const ActivityOwnerCol As String = "B"
Public Const ActivityNameCol As String = "C"
Public Const ActivityTypeCol As String = "D"
Public Const ActivityStartDateCol As String = "E"
Public Const ActivityEndDateCol As String = "F"
Public Const Prod1Col As String = "G"
Public Const ExpenseTypeCol As String = "H"
Public Const CurrencyCol As String = "I"
Public Const Amt1Col As String = "J"
Public Const PaymentDateCol As String = "K"
Public Const CustomerIDCol As String = "L"
Public Const AdditionalInformationCol As String = "M" 'MedEd Event Code
Public Const VendorCol As String = "N"
Public Const ActivityStateCol As String = "O"
Public Const ActivityCityCol As String = "P"
Public Const ExternalActivityIDCol As String = "Q"
Public Const ExternalExpenseIDCol As String = "R"
Public Const Prod2Col As String = "S"
Public Const Prod3Col As String = "T"
Public Const Prod4Col As String = "U"
Public Const Prod5Col As String = "V"
Public Const HCPEventCodeCol As String = "W"
Public Const HCPNameFromSpreadsheetCol As String = "X" 'HCP Traveler Name
Public Const OriginalTotalAmountCol As String = "Y" 'Total Expense Amount
Public Const EmployeeFirstNameCol As String = "Z" 'Booker Name
Public Const ManualSpendFormNameCol As String = "AA" 'Source File Name
Public Const UploadTemplateNameCol As String = "AB" 'Upload File Name


Public Sub MakeUploadSpreadsheet()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    
    Dim objXLApp As Object
    Dim objXLWb As Object
    Dim objXLSheet As Object
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim strWorkBook As String
    Dim strWorkSheet As String
    Dim ToRow As Integer
    Dim strTableName As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim TimeElapsed As Double
    Dim Step1 As Double
    Dim Step2 As Double
    Dim Step3 As Double
    
    
    CurrentDb.Execute ("q_Product 1 Text Mapping")
    CurrentDb.Execute ("q_Product 2 Text Mapping")
    CurrentDb.Execute ("q_Product 3 Text Mapping")
    CurrentDb.Execute ("q_Product 4 Text Mapping")
    CurrentDb.Execute ("q_Product 5 Text Mapping")

    'Updates the Activity and Expense Type
    CurrentDb.Execute ("q_Nature Text Mapping")
    
    CurrentDb.Execute ("q_Move Processed Records")
    
    
    'Set variables for upload template file name, sheet name, starting field and temp table
    strWorkBook = UploadTemplateFilePath
    strWorkSheet = "Worksheet"
    ToRow = 6
    strTableName = "tblProcessed Records"
    
    'Set recordset as temp table
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strTableName)
    
    'Create references to Excel upload template file
    Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open(strWorkBook)
    Set objXLSheet = objXLWb.Worksheets(strWorkSheet)
    
    strDate = Date
    strTime = Time
    strDate = Format(CStr(strDate), "YYYYMMDD")
    strTime = Format(CStr(strTime), "HHMMSS")
    strFilePath = "\\mmpfs04.endo.san\Shared\ASSC\Production\Upload_Spreadsheets\Airfare" & "_" & UserName & "_" & strDate & "_" & strTime & ".xlsx" 'Destination of file
    
    
    With rs
        Do Until .EOF
        
            If rs![Reportable Status] = "Reportable" Then
                objXLSheet.Range(ActivityCountryCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Destination Country Code]
                objXLSheet.Range(ActivityOwnerCol & ToRow).Value = "United States"
                objXLSheet.Range(ActivityNameCol & ToRow).Value = "Airfare_" & rs![ID] & "_" & rs![Ticket Number]
                objXLSheet.Range(ActivityTypeCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Activity Type]
                objXLSheet.Range(ActivityStartDateCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Ticket Departure Date]
                objXLSheet.Range(ActivityEndDateCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Ticket Departure Date]
                objXLSheet.Range(ExpenseTypeCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Expense Type]
                objXLSheet.Range(CurrencyCol & ToRow).Value = "USD"
                objXLSheet.Range(Amt1Col & ToRow).Value = rs![Reported Amount]
                objXLSheet.Range(PaymentDateCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Ticket Departure Date]
                objXLSheet.Range(CustomerIDCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Client Defined 11]
                objXLSheet.Range(Prod1Col & ToRow).Value = rs![Product 1 Text]
                objXLSheet.Range(ExternalActivityIDCol & ToRow).Value = "Airfare_" & rs![ID] & "_" & rs![Ticket Number]
                objXLSheet.Range(ExternalExpenseIDCol & ToRow).Value = "Airfare_" & rs![ID] & "_" & rs![Ticket Number]
                objXLSheet.Range(VendorCol & ToRow).Value = "Airfare"
                objXLSheet.Range(HCPEventCodeCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Client Defined 14]

                'Test if product 2-5 exist and only copy into upload template if they do
                If rs![Product 2 Text] <> "" Then
                    objXLSheet.Range(Prod2Col & ToRow).Value = rs![Product 2 Text]
                End If

                If rs![Product 3 Text] <> "" Then
                    objXLSheet.Range(Prod3Col & ToRow).Value = rs![Product 3 Text]
                End If

                If rs![Product 4 Text] <> "" Then
                    objXLSheet.Range(Prod4Col & ToRow).Value = rs![Product 4 Text]
                End If

                If rs![Product 5 Text] <> "" Then
                    objXLSheet.Range(Prod5Col & ToRow).Value = rs![Product 5 Text]
                End If
                
                objXLSheet.Range(ActivityCityCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Destination City Name]
                
                If rs![Destination Country Code] = "US" Then
                    objXLSheet.Range(ActivityStateCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Destination State-Province Code]
                End If
                objXLSheet.Range(HCPNameFromSpreadsheetCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Traveler Name]
                objXLSheet.Range(OriginalTotalAmountCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Paid Fare]
                objXLSheet.Range(EmployeeFirstNameCol & ToRow).Value = rs![Client Defined 08]
                objXLSheet.Range(ManualSpendFormNameCol & ToRow).Value = rs![file name]
                objXLSheet.Range(UploadTemplateNameCol & ToRow).Value = strFilePath
                
                'Adds file name from of this upload spreadsheet within the Archive table
                rs.Edit
                rs![Exported File Name].Value = strFilePath
                rs.Update
                
                ToRow = ToRow + 1
            End If
            
            .MoveNext
            
        Loop
    End With
    
    objXLSheet.Columns.autofit
    
    'Save wb using 'Save As' so Template is not overwritten
    objXLWb.SaveAs strFilePath
    objXLWb.Close
    
    MsgBox "The data has been Transferred - You can find the file here: \\mmpfs04.endo.san\Shared\ASSC\Production\Upload_Spreadsheets"
    
    
    
    CurrentDb.Execute ("q_Delete Processed HCP Flights")
    CurrentDb.Execute ("q_Archive Exported Flights")
    CurrentDb.Execute ("q_Delete Processed Temp Table")
    
    
ErrorHandler_Exit:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    'close up other rs objects
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    Set objXLSheet = Nothing
    Set objXLWb = Nothing

    'quit Excel
    If Not objXLApp Is Nothing Then objXLApp.Quit
    Set objXLApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    ' Display error information.
    MsgBox "Error number " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    ' Resume with statement following occurrence of error.
    Resume ErrorHandler_Exit
    

End Sub
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error? looks like `Format(CStr(strDate), "YYYYMMDD")` should do the job... except you might need to remove the `CStr`

Comment: Can you please show me where to add that? I dont know where to put that code. Currently what came out had a time stamp on it as well.

Comment: Did you write this code?

Comment: not from scratch, it was cobbled together from other databases that are accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Okay, so specifically which variable is not being exported in the format you expect? Also, what (exactly) does that data look like to start with.

Comment: ActivityStartDateCol
ActivityEndDateCol
PaymentDateCol
are the three variables, the date field they come from is [ticket departure date] and dates within that look like "3/14/2022". This field in access is formatted as a date field.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe give this a try?

```
            objXLSheet.Range(ActivityStartDateCol & ToRow).Value = format(rs![Ticket Departure Date],"mm/dd/yyyy")
            objXLSheet.Range(ActivityEndDateCol & ToRow).Value = format(rs![Ticket Departure Date],"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: You are a godsend! Thank you so much. I have been hitting me head against the wall for hours.